# Combine more than 1 image into a gif

Tags: java, android

I'm wondering if it's possible to combine more than 1 image into a gif?

So, essentially you import 2 photos and make a gif out of them.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes,it can! see this: http://makeagif.com/

Comment: I need it for a program I'm creating. Not an online reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, here is a way to do this:

- Create the final image as a `new BufferedImage(...)`
- get a `Graphics` object on the image with `image.getGraphics()`
- call `graphics.drawImage()` for each image you want to put on the larger image (you can load these images with `ImageIO`)
- use `ImageIO` to write the `BufferedImage` out as a GIF

Comment: @Denis, you didn't say you wanted an animated gif!  That's a totally different thing :-)

Comment: Ah! Sorry. I should have mentioned animated. Thanks though.